# Escaping the content of a template

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I use the twig include function in a template to output the content of another template, escaped for javascript ? Here is what I tried :

```
jQuery(".container").append('<div id="my-modal">{% 
  include 'MyBundle:MyFolder:myTemplate.html.twig'
  with {'my_var': var} |escape('js') %}</div>');
```

But the code inside myTemplate.html.twig is not escaped at all... how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Twig team answered me here very fast : https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/459#issuecomment-2286649

Here is what I did:

```
jQuery(".container").append('<div id="my-modal">{% filter escape('js') %}{% 
  include 'MyBundle:MyFolder:myTemplate.html.twig'
  with {'my_var': var} %}{% endfilter %}</div>');
```